# Going from full encrypted system to unencrypted /boot and encrypted / - how to be asked for the passphrase?

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, cryptsetup, dmcrypt

I had a fully encrypted system with `/boot` and `/` on the same device (`/dev/sd8` is root). `/` contained a keyfile under `/etc/luks/` so that I only needed to enter a passphrase when GRUB started, not afterwards. This proved to lead to very slow startup processes, so I wanted to change that.
I now have set up a separate `/boot` partition which is unencrypted. Decrypting the root by the kernel after GRUB seems to be much faster. With this setup, I do not need to enter a passphrase any longer.
This of course invalidates the whole idea of encryption, as the key is lying around unencrypted in my `/boot/initrd`. Therefore, I want the Kernel to ask for the passphrase on startup. Therefore I moved `/etc/luks/sda8_crypt.key` out of the way and deleted the relevant entry in `/etc/crypttab`. I added the following to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cryptdevice=afee3be7-e817-4e11-9918-1373dd5e6a33:sda8_crypt root=/dev/mapper/sda8_crypt quiet splash"
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="y"
```

And in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`:

```
ASKPASS=y
```

Despite of this, and after all the update-initramfs and update-grub2, I find myself at boot in the initramfs shell and need to cryptsetup, mount and chroot myself (anecdotically I am stuck there as just launching init no longer works).
The UUID provided to grub in the command line for the kernel is the one of /dev/sda8 (so not the mapped /dev/mapper/sda8_crypt).
I see from the grub.cfg-related scripts that Ubuntu adds an additional root= entry to the kernel command line, probably the UUID of the decrypted (mapped) device.

Where do I put which UUID to actually have ubuntu boot?
Luckily, I moved the old initrd and vmlinuz to new files, which are now an option for booting flawlessly as they still contain the encryption key.

For the UUIDs:

```
/dev/mapper/sda8_crypt: UUID="dbe3d3d7-eb2c-401b-a2c4-56a3e046a3ab" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" – 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="boot" UUID="46b05bc4-d3bc-44aa-ac31-3d192f5e2979" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="bd8ad2a8-8b87-4ac2-b06f-6e58159f767f"
/dev/sda8: UUID="afee3be7-e817-4e11-9918-1373dd5e6a33" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="8c7f615e-0898-468a-9489-18d0412b5436"
```

And the relevant line in the compiled grub.cfg:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-5.15.0-102-generic-key root=UUID=dbe3d3d7-eb2c-401b-a2c4-56a3e046a3ab ro  cryptdevice=afee3be7-e817-4e11-9918-1373dd5e6a33:sda8_crypt root=/dev/mapper/sda8_crypt quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I now realised what was wrong!
I had deleted /etc/crypttab, as I wanted to delete a reference to the keyfile. /etc/crypttab read as follows:

```
sda8_crypt    UUID=uuidofthephysicalpartition   /etc/luks/sda8_crypt.key,discard
```

Instead of this, I needed to change the setting to

```
sda8_crypt    UUID=uuidofthephysicalpartition    none
```

Et voilà, I am asked for the passphrase and can safely store my keyfile away on an external backup disk.
Now I still needed to clean up again /etc/default/grub, but my system behaves as it should.